# Yii: Getting the file extension while upload

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, file-extension

I am trying to upload `.pdf` file to server in `Yii`. I am doing this using `CUploadedFile`. File is successfully been saved to the server but i `don't` know how to save it with the extension. Here is what I am doing:

```
if (isset($_POST['UserItems'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['UserItems'];
            $model->recipe_file_url = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'recipe_file_url');
            if ($model->save()) {
                $model->recipe_file_url->saveAs('images\uploads\recipie' . rand(999, 9999) . CUploadedFile::getExtensionName());
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
            }
        }
```

I searched it out and found `::getExtensionName()` as a solution but it doesn't work. How to make it work, any help?

**EDIT**
When I run the above code, following `error` pops out:

> Property "UserItemsController._name" is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$model->recipe_file_url->getExtensionName()
```

Hope it works

Comment: Oh Thanks Man, Worked like a charm!